# Can you edit the "name" attribute for AWS resources via the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

In the AWS Console I can edit the name attribute for varying resources (e.g. EC2 instances, VPC resources, etc), but can this name attribute be modified via the CLI/SDK?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's just a tag. Make sure you are using `Name` (capitalized)

Example

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources "vpc-xxxxxxxxx" --tags Key=Name,Value=something-other-than-default
```

Comment: Thank you - very implicit, haven't run across that in any of the docs before.